# Disassemble SPIR binary to LLVM IR

Tags: opencl, llvm, llvm-ir

My understanding is that a SPIR binary is supposed to be LLVM bitcode and SPIR IR is a subset of LLVM IR. Additionally, SPIR is device agnostic. I've tried using the llvm-dis command on the binary I get from clGetProgramInfo with CL_PROGRAM_BINARIES as the parameter, but it tells me "Invalid bitcode signature". llvm-bcanalyzer returns "Invalid record at top-level".

I can go the opposite way by using Clang to turn my OpenCL kernel into either LLVM IR or LLVM bitcode. However, the bitcode file size is about 10x smaller so I'm pretty sure it's not the same as my SPIR binary.

Just to be complete, my GPU does have the *cl_khr_spir* extension.

1. Is my understanding of a SPIR binary as LLVN bitcode correct?
2. Is there a way to disassemble a SPIR binary to LLVM IR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in that SPIR **1.2** is a subset of LLVM IR (specifically LLVM 3.2). Note that the most recent version of SPIR (known as SPIR-V) is *not* derived from LLVM IR, and is a standalone, from-scratch intermediate representation.

Using `llvm-dis` is the correct way to disassemble an LLVM-based SPIR binary. Since SPIR 1.2 is derived from LLVM 3.2, this is only really guaranteed to work for an LLVM 3.2 version of `llvm-dis`. In practice, I've found that this still works fine with newer versions of LLVM, but there's no guarantee that this will always be the case.

Although your device supports the `cl_khr_spir` extension, there is no requirement for it to actually return a SPIR binary when you query `CL_PROGRAM_BINARIES` from `clGetProgramInfo`. Many platforms will instead return a native binary (e.g. x86 or the native GPU ISA), or some other intermediate representation (this is likely why LLVM is failing to recognise your binaries as being LLVM-based). There is no standardised mechanism for retrieving a SPIR binary via the OpenCL runtime API.

Using `clang` to compile an OpenCL C kernel into LLVM IR/SPIR 1.2 is the best way to get an LLVM bitcode file, which can then be disassembled with `llvm-dis`. Some vendors (e.g. Intel) also ship offline compilers with their OpenCL SDKs that provide dedicated commands/tools to do this.